# Did Rashi make halachic rulings?

Tags: halacha, rashi

Did Rashi issue any halachic rulings?  (Examples?)  Or did he simply provide useful and succinct explanations, drawn from the Sources, for those studying Torah?

Comment: We have some Responsa from Rashi. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rashi#Responsa

Comment: The chida addresses this question in Shem hagedolim

Comment: Rashi tefillin?

Comment: @JoelK that's a outgrowth of his explanation of the gemarra, but not necessarily a "ruling"

Comment: We never make such distinctions, we never categorize a Rabbi's statement into Halachic and non-Halachic. Everything Rashi said that does not merely explain the text is considered Rashi's Halacha and can be taken into consideration when Paskening. Same with Tosfos. So I heard and hold.

Comment: @AlBerko I think the answers below tend to disagree with you.

Answer (score 6):

From time to time Rashi gets into a discussion of actual halachic practice in his commentary. A few examples:

**Beitzah 24b**

> ובתשובת רבינו גרשום מאור הגולה מצאתי כמותי גם עתה בא אלי מכתב מגרמיי״ש שבא לשם אדם גדול זקן ויושב בישיבה מן רומא ושמו רבי קלונימוס ובקי בכל התלמוד והורה כן ונחלק עליהן
>
> And in the responsum of Rabbeinu Gershom the light of the exile I found [that he ruled] like me. Also now a letter came to me from Germany that a great elderly man came there and sat in the  yeshiva, and his name was R. Kalonimus, and he was an expert in the entire Talmud, and he ruled thusly and disagreed with them.

**Chullin 10b**

> על ידי היה מעשה והורה לי רבינו יעקב ב״ר יקר בעוף לאיסור
>
> I had such a case, and R. Yaakov b. Yakar ruled to me prohibitively by a bird.

**Rosh Hashanah 10a**

> והרבה טעו בשמועה זו ללמוד מכאן לספור יום שפוסקת בו למנין שבעה נקיים שהיו מפרשים סוף היום עולה לה בתחלתה דסוף יום שפוסקת בו עולה לה ראשון לשבעה נקיים וזו מדת בנות כותיים הוא ששנינו בהן יום שפוסקת בו סופרת למנין שבעה
>
> And many have erred with this teaching, to learn from here to count the day on which she stops towards the count of the seven clean [days]. For they explain “the end of the day counts as the beginning” that the end of the day on which she stops counts as the first towards the seven clean [days]. But this is the practice of Cuthean women, for it was taught of them “the day that she stops she counts toward count of seven”.

Comment: Actually quite a few of these in perek elu treifus.

Answer (score 5):

Yes, he did. Many of them can be found in works of his students as in Machzor Vitri and similar such seforim. More comprehensive, singular collections can be found in the following:

1. A collection (the first, I believe) of halachic rulings contained in responsa by Rashi titled ‘[Chofes Matmonim](http://hebrewbooks.org/32459)’.
2. A revised and annotated edition of the aforementioned collection was published by [R. Kasher](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Menachem_Mendel_Kasher) ([here](http://www.hebrewbooks.org/1143)).
3. R. Israel Elfenbein published a collection titled ‘Teshuvot Rashi’ ([here](http://www.hebrewbooks.org/1734)).

Answer (score 2):

This answer regards the Commentary of Rashi.

The Shem hagedolim writes:

> מצאתי בספר כתב יד ישן נושן וזה לשונו ראש לכל החיבירים שנתחברו דרך פירוש הם פירושי הרב רבינו שלמה בר יצחק. ואם רבו הלוחמים עליו, כלי סיימו עליו ותשובתו מתוך דבריו כולם נכוחים למבין, אין מעלתו ניכרת רק ליחידים כי במילה אחת יכלול לפעמים תירוצים של חבילי קושיות אלא שלא כיון הרב בהם לענין פסק. עד כאן לשונו. והא דגמר אומר אלא שלא כיון הרב לפסק הלכה הכי חזיתיה לרדב''ז בתשובה חלק א'סימן ק''ט שכתב וזה לשונו כל שכן שיש בידנו כלל גדול כי רש''י מפרש הוא ולא פוסק ויותר יש לסמוך על בעלי הפסק. גם מרן בבית יוסף אורח חיים סימן י'כתב דרש''י מפרש הוא ולא פוסק עיין שם.ואל תתמה על החפץ דמי לנו גדול מרש''י ואיך הרדב''ז ומרן כתבו דיש לסמוך יותר על הפוסקים, כי עיניך לנכים יביטו דברי הרב בהם לענין פסק ותנוח דעתך, דהכוונה דרש''י עצמו עיקר כונתו לפרש ולא כיון לפסק. ומאחר בקבלה בידם דרש''י עצמו לא כיון לענין פסק אם כן שפיר קאמרי מרן והרדב''ז דיש לסמוך יותר על בעלי הפסק. וזה תלמוד ערוך פרק יש נוחלין... אמנם כאשר רש''י כותב בפירוש לענין פסק כמו באסור והיתר שלפעמים פוסק הדין בפירוש, אז ודאי דסברתו נחשבת כאחד מגדולי הפוסקים וזה ברור, וכן כתבתי במקום אחר ועיין בהלכות קטנות חלק ה' סימן קי''ז ובספר בית דוד חושן משפט סימן ה' אות ך' דיש חולקין בזה וכן הרב מעדני מלך הלכות ציצית אות ס''א חלק על מרן בזה דחש לרש''י שפירש הסוגיא אף על פי שהוא עצמו סובר שאינו אליבא דהלכתא, וכי לא יחוש לחורבא דנפיק מינה וכו' עיין שם.

Summary. Often Rashi addresses the psak clearly. Most times he only comments and we cannot be sure that he holds the Halacha as his comment. Radbaz and Bet Yosef s that  commentary is not a psak.  But some acharonim, the Rama mifano and Bet David hold that his comment has a strong halachic value..

Note. It's hard to think that the right pshat regarding the conclusion of the Gemara is not the right Halacha.

Answer (score 1):

This [Halachipedia article](https://www.halachipedia.com/index.php?title=Rashi) notes that there are two halacha seforim by Rashi: one ("**Sefer HaPardes**") was written by him and the other ("**Sefer Likutei Pardes**") was his halachik rulings compiled by his talmidim.

### 1) **Sefer HaPardes**

([hebrewbooks.org link](http://www.hebrewbooks.org/8962))

[image]

---

### 2) **Sefer Likutei Pardes**

([hebrewbooks.org link](http://www.hebrewbooks.org/1747))

[image]

Comment: I don't think this is accurate. There are way more than two books in the Rashi students collection (known as ספרי דבי רשי) like Sefer HaOrah, Siddur Rashi, Issur veHeter, and I'm not convinced Rashi himself wrote Pardes and not a student, p R' Shemaya